# optimizing MySQL for traffic analytics system

Tags: mysql, index, mongodb, scalability, memcached

**background :**

I've developed a URL shortener system like Bitly with same features , so the system also tracks clickers info and represent as graphs to the person who has shorten the link as analytics data.
currently I'm using MySQL and have a table to store click info with this schema:

```
visit_id (int)
ip (int)
date (datetime)
country
browser
device
os
referrer (varchar)
url_id (int)  //as foreign key to the shortened URL
```

and for now , just the `url_id` field has index

The system should represent click analytics in the time periods the user wants, for example past hour, past 24 hours , the past month , ...

for example to generate graphs for past month , I do following queries:

```
SELECT all DAY(date) AS period, COUNT( * ) 
                        FROM (

                        SELECT * 
                        FROM visits
                        WHERE url_id =  '$url_id'
                        ) AS URL
                        WHERE DATE > DATE_SUB( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP( ) , INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) 
                        GROUP BY DAY( DATE )

//another query to display clicker browsers in this period
//another query to display clicker countries in this period
// ...
```

**issues:**

- for a shortened link with about 500,000 clicks , it takes about 3-4 seconds to calculate just the first query , so for total queries about 10-12 seconds which is terrible.
- lots of memory and CPU is needed to run such queries

**questions :**

1- how to improve and optimize the structure , so the analytics of high
   traffic links will be shown in less than 1 second(like bitly and similar web apps) and with less usage
   of CPU and RAM ? should I make an index on the fields `date`,
   `country`, `browser`, `device`, `os`, `referrer` ? if yes , how to do
   that for the field `date` because I should group clicks some times by
   `DAY(date)`, sometimes by `HOUR(date)`, sometimes by `MINUTE(date)`
   and ...

2- is MySQL suitable for this application? assume at maximum my application should handle 100 million links and 10 billion clicks on them totally. Should I consider switching to an NoSQL solution for example?

3- if MySQL is ok , is my database design and table structure proper and well designed for my application needs? or you have better recommendations and suggestions?

**UPDATE:** I made an index on column `referrer` but it didn't help at all and also damaged the performance and I think that's because of the low cardinality of this column (also others) and the big resulting index size related to the RAM of my server.

I think making index on these columns would not help to solve my problem, my idea is about one of these:

1- if using MySQL, maybe generating statistics using background processing for high traffic links is better instead of calculating lively at the user request.

2- using some caching solution like memcached to help MySQL with high traffic links.

3- using a NoSQL such as MongoDB and solutions like Map-Reduce which I am poorly familiar with and haven't used ever.

what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your query to something along these lines. I expect MySQL will generate a simpler execution plan.

```
SELECT date(date) period, count(*) clicks
FROM visits
WHERE url_id = 3
  AND DATE > DATE_SUB( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP( ) , INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) 
GROUP BY period;
```

If returning results on high-traffic links in one second is a hard requirement, you might need to upgrade your hardware.

Expect to need an index on each column used in a WHERE clause. You might benefit from some multicolumn indexes; {url_id, date} is a candidate.

Test at scale, if that's at all possible. (It's usually possible, although it might take some time.) Use EXPLAIN to see what MySQL is doing with your queries.

You don't *have* to query browsers, countries, and everything else all at one time. When I was running web development, I rarely looked at countries--they weren't relevant to the niche I was working in. Also consider other asynchronous UI technologies.

PostgreSQL has a better optimizer. It might work better than MySQL. Test it.